# Put divs next to eachother based on left margin to parent

Tags: css, html, positioning

[image: Thing I'm trying to achieve]

The picture is what I'm trying to achieve. Basicly I'm trying to make one wrapper div and be able to place a variable number of divs within it, based on the left margin to the lefternmost part of the parent wrapper.

I would like to be able to say something like:

```
.div1 { margin-left:5%; }
.div2 { margin-left:30%; }
.div3 { margin-left:85%; }
```

And achieve what is seen in the picture.
However, I noticed (which I had assumed would happen), that the divs are unwilling to cooperate; when I add a `float:left`, they seem to add the margins to eachother (as in div2 gets a `margin-left:30%` in addition to its 5% left margin and its 10% width, making the div2 appear at 45% from the lefternmost part of the wrapper.

I realize I could just take into account the previous margins, and put the margin-left of div2 to 30%-15%=15% and get the right result, but I'd like to know if there's an approach to just do it with the margin-left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't float them; rather, position them absolutely at the location so that they 'overlap' in a sense; the margins will hold them apart in the way you want.

Example:

```
.green {background-color: green; position: absolute}
.one {width:10%; margin-left:5%}
.two {width:20%; margin-left: 30%}
.three {width:10%; margin-left: 85%}
```

Demo at:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mu4GU/

Comment: Thank you. I had attempted with absolute positions, but it messed the rest of my layout up, so I thought it wasn't feasible. I've now tried to rebuild it with absolute positioning and am getting a nice result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this with floating and not using absolute position.

HTML

```
<div id="page">
<div id="box1">10%</div>
<div id="box2">25%</div>
<div id="box3">15%</div>
```

CSS

```
#page{width:100%;height:200px; background-color:#000;}
#box1{height:200px; background-color:red; width:10%; margin-left:5%;float:left;}
#box2{height:200px; background-color:green; width:25%; margin-left:15%;float:left;}
#box3{height:200px; background-color:blue; width:15%; margin-left:30%;float:left;}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pDxXB/